# Want to Convert pandas df code to pyspark df code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

pandas df code is

```
Data = data[data['ObservationDate'] == max(data['ObservationDate'])].reset_index()
Data_world = Data.groupby(["ObservationDate"])["Confirmed","Active_case","Recovered","Deaths"].sum().reset_index()
Data_world
```

Dataframe structure is this.

```
SNo     ObservationDate     Province/State  Country/Region  Last Update     Confirmed   Deaths  Recovered   Active_case
0   1   01/22/2020  Anhui   China   1/22/2020 17:00     1   0   0   1
1   2   01/22/2020  Beijing     China   1/22/2020 17:00     14  0   0   14
2   3   01/22/2020  Chongqing   China   1/22/2020 17:00     6   0   0   6
3   4   01/22/2020  Fujian  China   1/22/2020 17:00     1   0   0   1
4   5   01/22/2020  Gansu   China   1/22/2020 17:00     0   0   0   0
```

and want output like this

```
ObservationDate     Confirmed   Active_case     Recovered   Deaths
0   03/22/2020  335957  223441  97882   14634
```

How to filter on max date?

```
max_date =  df.select(max("ObservationDate")).first()
group_data = df.groupBy("ObservationDate")
group_data.agg({'Confirmed':'sum', 'Deaths':'sum', 'Recovered':'sum', 'Active_case':'sum'}).show()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: group_data = df.groupBy("ObservationDate")
group_data.agg({'Confirmed':'sum', 'Deaths':'sum', 'Recovered':'sum', 'Active_case':'sum'}).show()

Comment: better start from the business case rather than the code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. You can `collect` your `max` date first, then use it in a `filter` before you `groupBy` and `aggregate.`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
max_date=df.select(F.max("ObservationDate")).collect()[0][0]
df.filter(F.col("ObservationDate")==max_date)\
.groupBy("ObservationDate")\
.agg({'Confirmed':'sum', 'Deaths':'sum', 'Recovered':'sum', 'Active_case':'sum'})\
.show()
```